# Unexpected program output

Tags: c, database, output

I suspect my program is not working properly. The output is not what I would expect. When I run this program the first time, the result is different than if we repeat the action without closing the program, for example add new record..

Here is the source code I have as of now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct emp{
    char name[40];
    int age;
    float bs;
};
main()
{
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    struct emp e;
    char choice;
    char another;
    char empname[40];
    fp = fopen("emp.dat","rb+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fp = fopen("emp.dat", "wb+");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
    system("cls");
    printf("1. Add New Record\n");
    printf("2. Modify to Record\n");
    printf("3. Delete to Record\n");
    printf("4. Display Records\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    choice = getche();               
    printf("\n");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case '1':
            another = 'Y';
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
            while(another == 'Y')
            {
                printf("Enter name, age and basic salary: \n");
                scanf("%s%d%f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
                fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
                printf("Add more records (Y/N)\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c", &another);
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("Enter name of employee to modify record!\n");
            scanf("%s", empname);
            rewind(fp);
            while(fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp) == 1)
            {
                while(strcmp(e.name,empname) == 0)
                {
                    fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
                    printf("Enter new name, age, basic salary!\n");
                    scanf("%s %d %f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
                    fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
                }
            }
            break;
         case '3':
            another = 'Y';
            while(another == 'Y')
            {
                rewind(fp);
                ft = fopen("temp.dat", "wb+");
                printf("Enter name of employee to delete  record!\n");
                scanf("%s", &empname);
                while(fread(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp) == 1)
                {
                    while(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)
                    {
                        fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
                        fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,ft);                          
                    }
                    fclose(fp);
                    fclose(ft);
                    remove("emp.dat");
                    rename("temp.dat","emp.dat");
                    fp = fopen("emp.dat","wb+");
                }
                printf("Do you want to delete more record/s (Y/N)!\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getche();
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            rewind(fp);
            while(fread(&e, sizeof(e), 1, fp) == 1)
            printf("%s %d %0.2f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);
            break;
        case '0':
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Enter correct choice!\n");  
            break;  
    }
        fclose(fp);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Here is my program running, and with an example output:

[image: Image displaying program output]

Comment: The output is not what you expect but you do not show what you expect (just write the expected output manually), please do so. Also please explain what you expect. Also explain what the purpose of the program is, why is the desired output what you expect, is there a logic? Give an overview of what the purpose of the program is. All of that should be explained and clarified by you, not guessed by readers.

Comment: Does the undesired output only occut in certain situations? E.g. for which input? Is all of the shown code needed to demonstrate the unwanted behaviour? If not please focus. I.e. make a [mcve].

Comment: Can you write a more to the point title? With the current one, you suffer the risk of being ignored. Can you focus on what seems to go wrong, instead of that it looks unexpected?

Comment: For example, add records and then select choice 4. It should display all records. But nothing is being displayed. You can see in attached picture. Nothing is displaying. Further if you try to modify record. It asks to enter new name age and bs. But then it keep asking again and again once you even entered. I think if you will execute this code and will try to use all 5 modules. You will come to know issues.

Comment: @Yunnosch if you have checked the code?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last comment. Could you rephrase?

Comment: @Yunnosch I try to explain again. It is a switch case program. There are cases i.e. 1 for adding new record, CASE 2 for modifying record, CASE 3 for deleting a record and 4 for displaying records list. Now first I go into first CASE 1, and add records there. Now I wanted to display all these records list on screen. I go into CASE 4. Because in CASE 4 there is code for displaying all these records. It should display all records when I go into CASE 4. But it is displaying nothing. What is wrong in code there? Did you get my point?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information and details, instead of hiding them in a comment.

Comment: If the output of CASE 1 and 4 is questionable, then focus on one of them. Can you demonstrate that case 4 is cabable of outputting hard-coded content? Can you use a debugger to verify that case 1 achieves correct storing? Try to find a problem in a single case, not in a combination, then simplif your problem by anaylsing and demonstrating that single-case problem. You might also want to ask a quesiton on a problem with one case only. Make sure that one case is bullet-proof, then go on to the next one. I recommend to first bring the output to perfection, it can become part of your tools.